# What is Unison Synchronization?

Tags: mixing, minimal-music

I am reading the following article

> Schwarz, K. Robert. "Steve Reich: Music as a Gradual Process: Part
>   I." Perspectives of New Music (1980): 373-392.

[Here is a paywalled link](https://www.jstor.org/stable/832600). On page 385, there is a passage about [Steve Reich's *It's Gonna Rain*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vugqRAX7xQE) .  I don't understand the first sentence of that passage:

> *It's Gonna Rain* is two parts, the first taking the title phrase from a
>   unison synchronization of two channels through a complete shift of
>   phase, and then back to the original unison again.

What is a "unison synchronization of two channels"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unison** usually means that two instruments are playing the same notes together. In this case, we have two tracks playing back the same recording - of the phrase "It's gonna rain".

**Synchronisation** means that things are aligned in time.

And the **two channels** are just the Left and Right channels in a stereo mix

Listening to the piece on headphones might make things clearer - I think the section being written about starts around 2:30 and ends about 7:30. You can hear the Left and Right stereo channels go out of phase, and then come back into synchronisation again:

Having said that, the particular phrasing "unison synchronization of two channels" is odd. Talking about unison *and* synchronisation is a bit tautological as the concept of unison includes the concept of being in sync; and arguably it's not so much that the channels themselves that are in sync so much as the snippets of audio that are being repeated.